# I Can't Connect To WiFi anymore

Tags: pi-3, wifi, raspbian-stretch

I followed some instructions from the raspberry pi site for updating my OS, upon reboot I can no longer connect to WiFi. My WiFi icon in the menu is saying there are "No wireless interfaces found." I have tried to adjust the Localisation, but "Set WiFi Country" is not clickable. My network credentials are correct in the Configuration File. However, in ifconfig there is no wlan interface. I am using a RPi 3 with built in capabilities so there is no dongle. The hardware and power supply have not changed at all since performing the update and there are not messages related to wifi. I have tried a lot of the troubleshooting from this site, but to no avail.

My Pi is running Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.3 (stretch) And my kernel version is 6.1.63-v7+

Thanks! ~Jess

Comment: What instructions? What did you ACTUALLY do? Stretch is obsolete and hasn't been updated in years. If you have kernel 6.1 you probably used rpi-update and ignored the warnings. Restore from your backup.

Answer (score 0):

> My Pi is running Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.3 (stretch) And my kernel version is 6.1.63-v7+

You have *goofed* rather badly if your system has `stretch` installed with a 6.1 kernel. Maybe the *"instructions from the raspberry pi site for updating my OS"* that you followed weren't clear?

From this point - assuming your ***"update"*** was written to your SD card - you have two options:

1. restore your `stretch` installation from a backup
2. install an OS from *scratch* using the [Raspberry Pi Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/)*

* If you have any files on your system (SD card) that you want to preserve, you'll need to install your new OS to a second SD card.

If you interact with your RPi through a keyboard and monitor, you might consider downloading the [***legacy version*** (`bullseye`) of the OS](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/#raspberry-pi-os-legacy). The *legacy version* will avoid the *"hiccups"* with `Wayland` - the X-windows replacement that premieres in `bookworm`, and possibly get you an OS that's a bit more stable.

If you need help restoring files from your old `stretch` system (*and you installed on a new/different SD card!*), you should ask about that in another question.